# How to hover over a node to highlight specific links in Vega

Tags: javascript, networking, visualization, vega, force-directed-graph

I'm new in VEGA and I am using [this example](https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/force-directed-layout/) provided by developers to plot a network. However, I'm trying  to highlight the links when I hover into nodes.

I have tried to follow the [edge bundling example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/examples/vega/edge-bundling) to achieve that. Then, into the signals and Marks:
Signals:

```
  "signals": [    { "name": "colorIn", "value": "firebrick" },
{ "name": "colorOut", "value": "forestgreen" },
{ "name": "originX", "update": "width / 2" },
{ "name": "originY", "update": "height / 2" },
{
  "name": "active", "value": null,
  "on": [
    { "events": "symbol:mouseover", "update": "datum.id" },
    { "events": "mouseover[!event.item]", "update": "null" }
  ]
}
```

Marks->"path"->"encode"->"update"

```
       "stroke": [
            {"test": "datum.source === active", "signal": "colorOut"},
            {"test": "datum.target === active", "signal": "colorIn"},
            {"value": "steelblue"}
          ],
```

Comment: Please mark your old questions as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This highlights the active node as yellow.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "A node-link diagram with force-directed layout, depicting character co-occurrence in the novel Les Misérables.",
  "width": 700,
  "height": 500,
  "padding": 0,
  "autosize": "none",
  "signals": [
    {"name": "cx", "update": "width / 2"},
    {"name": "cy", "update": "height / 2"},
    {
      "name": "nodeRadius",
      "value": 8,
      "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 1, "max": 50, "step": 1}
    },
    {
      "name": "nodeCharge",
      "value": -30,
      "bind": {"input": "range", "min": -100, "max": 10, "step": 1}
    },
    {
      "name": "linkDistance",
      "value": 30,
      "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 5, "max": 100, "step": 1}
    },
    {"name": "static", "value": true, "bind": {"input": "checkbox"}},
    {
      "description": "State variable for active node fix status.",
      "name": "fix",
      "value": false,
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "symbol:mouseout[!event.buttons], window:mouseup",
          "update": "false"
        },
        {"events": "symbol:mouseover", "update": "fix || true"},
        {
          "events": "[symbol:mousedown, window:mouseup] > window:mousemove!",
          "update": "xy()",
          "force": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "description": "Graph node most recently interacted with.",
      "name": "node",
      "value": null,
      "on": [
        {"events": "symbol:mouseover", "update": "fix === true ? item() : node"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "description": "Flag to restart Force simulation upon data changes.",
      "name": "restart",
      "value": false,
      "on": [{"events": {"signal": "fix"}, "update": "fix && fix.length"}]
    },
    {
      "name": "active",
      "value": null,
      "on": [
        {"events": "symbol:mouseover", "update": "datum.name"},
        {"events": "mouseover[!event.item]", "update": "null"}
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "node-data",
      "url": "data/miserables.json",
      "format": {"type": "json", "property": "nodes"}
    },
    {
      "name": "link-data",
      "url": "data/miserables.json",
      "format": {"type": "json", "property": "links"}
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "domain": {"data": "node-data", "field": "group"},
      "range": {"scheme": "category20c"}
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "name": "nodes",
      "type": "symbol",
      "zindex": 1,
      "from": {"data": "node-data"},
      "on": [
        {
          "trigger": "fix",
          "modify": "node",
          "values": "fix === true ? {fx: node.x, fy: node.y} : {fx: fix[0], fy: fix[1]}"
        },
        {"trigger": "!fix", "modify": "node", "values": "{fx: null, fy: null}"}
      ],
      "encode": {
        "enter": {"stroke": {"value": "white"}},
        "update": {
          "fill": {
            "signal": "datum.name==active?'yellow': scale('color', datum.group)"
          },
          "size": {"signal": "2 * nodeRadius * nodeRadius"},
          "cursor": {"value": "pointer"}
        }
      },
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "force",
          "iterations": 300,
          "restart": {"signal": "restart"},
          "static": {"signal": "static"},
          "signal": "force",
          "forces": [
            {"force": "center", "x": {"signal": "cx"}, "y": {"signal": "cy"}},
            {"force": "collide", "radius": {"signal": "nodeRadius"}},
            {"force": "nbody", "strength": {"signal": "nodeCharge"}},
            {
              "force": "link",
              "links": "link-data",
              "distance": {"signal": "linkDistance"}
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "path",
      "from": {"data": "link-data"},
      "interactive": false,
      "encode": {
        "update": {"stroke": {"value": "#ccc"}, "strokeWidth": {"value": 0.5}}
      },
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "linkpath",
          "require": {"signal": "force"},
          "shape": "line",
          "sourceX": "datum.source.x",
          "sourceY": "datum.source.y",
          "targetX": "datum.target.x",
          "targetY": "datum.target.y"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you David, but I'd like to highlight the links! @david-bacci

Comment: Thank you, @DavidBacci, but I'd like to highlight the links!