# How to hover over a node to highlight specific LINKS in Vega?

Tags: networking, vega, force-directed-graph

I'm new in VEGA and I am using [this example](https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/force-directed-layout/) provided by developers to plot a network. So I'm trying to highlight the LINKS and NEIGHBORHOOD associated with a determined node while hovering this node. The links could be highlighted with a different color and links with a higher oppacity, for instance.

I have tried to follow the [edge bundling example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/examples/vega/edge-bundling) to achieve that. Then, into the signals and Marks:
Signals:

```
  "signals": [    { "name": "colorIn", "value": "firebrick" },
{ "name": "colorOut", "value": "forestgreen" },
{ "name": "originX", "update": "width / 2" },
{ "name": "originY", "update": "height / 2" },
{
  "name": "active", "value": null,
  "on": [
    { "events": "symbol:mouseover", "update": "datum.id" },
    { "events": "mouseover[!event.item]", "update": "null" }
  ]
}
```

Marks->"path"->"encode"->"update"

```
       "stroke": [
            {"test": "datum.source === active", "signal": "colorOut"},
            {"test": "datum.target === active", "signal": "colorIn"},
            {"value": "steelblue"}
          ],
```

Indeed, @DavidBacci [tried to help me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76359429/how-to-hover-over-a-node-to-highlight-specific-links-in-vega/76359565#76359565), but he highlighted just the hover node.

Comment: Please mark your old questions as solved...

Comment: You can see link highlighting at the following example and reuse the code from there: https://github.com/PBI-David/Deneb-Showcase#organisation-tree-chart